# How can place marker on an image using JavaScript that doesn't change after zooming

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, css-position

this is our code but this code is give me the coordinates according to the body relative but when i change the zoom then its gives me different values i want to get coordinates and save in my backend that cannot be change this is my code

```
function FindPosition(oElement) {
    console.log(oElement);
    console.log(oElement.pageX);
    if (typeof (oElement.offsetParent) != "undefined") {
      for (var posX = 0, posY = 0; oElement; oElement = oElement.offsetParent) {
        posX += oElement.offsetLeft;
        posY += oElement.offsetTop;
      }
      return [posX, posY];
    }
    else {
      return [oElement.x, oElement.y];
    }
  }

  function GetCoordinates(e) {
    var PosX = 0;
    var PosY = 0;
    var ImgPos;
    ImgPos = FindPosition(myImg.current);
    // console.log(document.documentElement.scrollTop);
    console.log(myImg);
    if (!e) {
      var e = window.event
    };
    if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
      PosX = e.pageX;
      PosY = e.pageY;
    }
    else if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {
      PosX = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
        + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      PosY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
        + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    PosX = PosX - ImgPos[0];
    PosY = PosY - ImgPos[1];

  }
```

here is jsx which is written in react js

```
      <div className="map" ref={"Here is map image"} onMouseDown={GetCoordinates}>
        <img className='mapImage' src={map} alt="" />
        <RoomIcon className="markerIcon" />
      </div>
```

this is the css code

```
.map {
  /* height: 100px; */
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  /* overflow: scroll; */
  margin-top: 18px;
  position: relative;
}

.mapForm .map img {
  margin-top: 18px;
  /* width: ; */
  /* width: 1900px; */
  /* zoom: 150%; */
}

.mapImage {
  width: 600px;
  /* zoom: 600%; */
}

.markerIcon {
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  color: #e24e40;
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: provide html and css code as well

Comment: added please help. very stuck almost 2 weeks gone but my problem is not solved

Answer (score 0):

You should save the relative (i.e. in percent) position of the marker on the image.

You can use getBoundingClientRect to simplify calculations:

```js
const imgRect = myImg.current.getBoundingClientRect(); // imgRect is relative to viewport
const {clientX, clientY} = e; // clientX and clientY are relative to viewport
// since both are relative to viewport, it's useless to try to get their absolute position to the document. Simply compute their pos differences
const posXpct = (clientX - imgRect.x)*100 / imgRect.width;
const posYpct = (clientY - imgRect.y)*100 / imgRect.height;
```

Then you store posXpct and posYpct. And to position your marker from the previously saved values:

```js
marker.style.position.left = posXpct+'%';
marker.style.position.top = posYpct+'%';
```

The additional advantage is that your marker will stay in place even if you resize physically the map (for instance on responsive devices with a width in %).

Don't forget to place the marker tip on this exact position, with something like (assuming your "tip" is at the bottom-center of the marker):

```css
.marker {
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

by using leaflet library you can change the address by the image

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).